# Dataweave JSON to XML format-Mule-4

Tags: dataweave, mule4

I am a beginner in using dataweave transformation, I am  trying to write a Mule 4 dataweave expression to convert input JSON into output XML format, I have a payload in JSON format and I want to convert it into a specific XML format, below is the actual JSON along with output XML

product-id(XML) tag will come from = name attribute of PBSI__Item__r tag of JSON
and allocation value in XML comes from name attribute of PBSI__Inventory__r tag

JSON:

```
[
  {
    "PBSI__Item__r": {
      "Id": null,
      "type": "PBSI__PBSI_Item__c",
      "Name": "116065"
    },
    "PBSI__Inventory__r": [
      {
        "Id": null,
        "type": "PBSI__PBSI_Inventory__c",
        "PBSI__Real_Quantity__c": "13.0"
      }
    ],
    "PBSI__Location__r": {
      "Id": null,
      "type": "PBSI__PBSI_Location__c",
      "Name": "OB043"
    },
    "Id": null,
    "type": "PBSI__Lot__c"
  },
  {
    "PBSI__Item__r": {
      "Id": null,
      "type": "PBSI__PBSI_Item__c",
      "Name": "116066"
    },
    "PBSI__Inventory__r": [
      {
        "Id": null,
        "type": "PBSI__PBSI_Inventory__c",
        "PBSI__Real_Quantity__c": "1.0"
      }
    ],
    "PBSI__Location__r": {
      "Id": null,
      "type": "PBSI__PBSI_Location__c",
      "Name": "OA011"
    },
    "Id": null,
    "type": "PBSI__Lot__c"
  }
]
```

output XML:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<inventory xmlns="http://www.demandware.com/xml/impex/inventory/2007-05-31">
  <inventory-list>
    <header list-id="Hastens_Inventory">
      <default-instock>false</default-instock>
      <use-bundle-inventory-only>false</use-bundle-inventory-only>
    </header>
    <records>
      <record product-id="116065">
        <allocation>13</allocation>
        <allocation-timestamp>2019-04-24T07:09:51.954Z</allocation-timestamp>
      </record>
      <record product-id="116066">
        <allocation>1</allocation>
        <allocation-timestamp>2019-04-24T07:09:51.965Z</allocation-timestamp>
      </record>
    </records>
  </inventory-list>
</inventory>
```

Comment: You have to provide the rules to transform the JSON to the XML, before trying to write a DataWeave script. Where does each element and attribute should come from?

Comment: Thanks aled, I have added it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help you get to a solution and as well learn the way to do it, I haven't given out a full blow solution, so that you could use this as a starting point (almost 80% done).

As well to include the namespace, follow the link https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dataweave-cookbook-include-xml-namespaces

```
{
    inventory:{
    inventorylist: {
        header @("list-id":"Hastens_Inventory"):
         { 
             "default-instock":false,
             "use-bundle-inventory-only":false
         },
         records: {(payload map
         {
             record @("product-id": $.PBSI__Item__r.Name): {
                 allocation: $.PBSI__Inventory__r[0].PBSI__Real_Quantity__c,
                 "allocation-timestamp": now()
             }
         })}

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Salim, you forgot the `{(...)}` around the `payload map ...`. This is generating multiple `records` elements

Comment: Hi Jorge, you are right, could help me to do that, I tried in many ways but getting syntax error

Comment: I had left it so that Pankaj could work a bit on the script. The solution was not full blown so that alongside the solution there is some learning/working involved as well.

Comment: Updated the script to fold records into one instance.